# how configure apache passenger in ubuntu 11.10 for rails app

Tags: apache, passenger

i am using linode vps to deploy rails application i have successfully install ruby and rails,mysql and apache with passenger.

here is my host file in /etc/host

```
     127.0.0.1                          localhost.localdomain localhost
     198.58.100.126                     foo.qitch1.com       foo
```

and i have also copy some lines after install passenger in httpd.conf file

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/passenger-3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so

   PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/passenger-3.0.17

  PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/ruby
```

which is including in apache2.conf

now i make file in /atc/apache2/sites_available with name generate_pdf.com

where generate_pdf is name of my app.and this file has code

```
         NameVirtualHost *:80

 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName aziz.qitch1.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/generate_pdf/public
   RailsEnv production
   <Directory /var/www/generate_pdf/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but when i start server and i visit this url  aziz.qitch1.com

nothing is loaded and i have this in shell

```
     NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a related problem, and came across http://old.thoughtsincomputation.com/posts/using-phusion-passenger-and-apache2-on-ubuntu-with-rvm-and-gemsets, which suggested putting the VirtualHost code in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/virtual.conf`. This resolved my problem, may help yours as well.

Note that I didn't have the `IfModule` the article uses, my VirtualHost code was just as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.yournamehere.com
   # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
   DocumentRoot /rails_app_folder/app_name/public
   <Directory /rails_app_folder/app_name/public>
      # This relaxes Apache security settings.
      AllowOverride all
      # MultiViews must be turned off.
      Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```